# why is there a timestamp error in command?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE speed_detection 
(
reg serial PRIMARY KEY,
direction VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
occupants INT NOT NULL, 
entrance_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
exit_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'without time zone NOT NULL,
exit_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL

Comment: Please describe your problem clearly. I don't see any error with that code. It works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=626232c67f7362c5e66cb917f9678e94

Comment: What exactly is the error you get? Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the **exact** error message  - but [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Comment: added error as requested

Comment: The SQL you have posted contains several  definitions that are specific to PostgreSQL, it is not going to work on MySQL. You have to decide where to go from there, whether you should use PostgreSQL instead of MySQL, or if you want help porting your table definition to the closest equivalent in MySQL.